# Why is Silverpop not accepting my XML API call?

Tags: api

I’m working on running a few tests on the Silverpop API, toward an eventual goal of uploading CSVs each evening to update a Silverpop table. I was able to successfully upload csv and xml files and get an oauth access token for the API. However, I’m having trouble with my first actual call.

Here is what I am attempting to send:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Envelope>
    <Body>
        <ImportList>
            <MAP_FILE>silverPopTest.xml</MAP_FILE>
            <SOURCE_FILE>silverPopTest.csv</SOURCE_FILE>
            <EMAIL>Nicholas@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com</EMAIL>
        </ImportList>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

And here is the 'fault string’ that I am receiving back:
    Missing 'xml'parameter

I’m not sure what that means.

I believe I am including all of the required parameters for this command per the docs. I have tried both with and without the “xml” line, as application/xml and text/xml, and a variety of other variations. For reference, here is the code for my entire call:

```
<cfhttp method="POST" url="https://api3.ibmmarketingcloud.com/XMLAPI">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/xml" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/xml"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer #accessToken#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#xmlBody#">
</cfhttp>
```

This is the error xml:

```
<Envelope><Body><RESULT><SUCCESS>false</SUCCESS></RESULT><Fault><Request/><FaultCode/><FaultString>Missing 'xml'parameter</FaultString><detail><error><errorid>52</errorid><module/><class>SP.API</class><method/></error></detail></Fault></Body></Envelope>
```

This is my CSV file:

```
"userid","Email","firstName","lastName"
"123fdasTEST1asdf321","nicholas+test1@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com","testFirst 1","testLast 1"
"123fdasTEST2asdf321","nicholas+test2@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com","testFirst 2","testLast 2"
```

This is my 'map' file:

```
    <LIST_IMPORT>
        <LIST_INFO>
            <ACTION>ADD_AND_UPDATE</ACTION>
            <LIST_ID>9999999</LIST_ID>
            <FILE_TYPE>0</FILE_TYPE>
            <HASHEADERS>true</HASHEADERS>
        </LIST_INFO>
        <COLUMNS>
            <COLUMN>
                <NAME>userid</NAME>
                <TYPE>0</TYPE>
                <IS_REQUIRED>true</IS_REQUIRED>
                <KEY_COLUMN>true</KEY_COLUMN>
            </COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>
                <NAME>Email</NAME>
                <TYPE>9</TYPE>
                <IS_REQUIRED>true</IS_REQUIRED>
            </COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>
                <NAME>firstName</NAME>
                <TYPE>0</TYPE>
                <IS_REQUIRED>true</IS_REQUIRED>
            </COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>
                <NAME>lastName</NAME>
                <TYPE>0</TYPE>
                <IS_REQUIRED>true</IS_REQUIRED>
            </COLUMN>
        </COLUMNS>
        <MAPPING>
            <COLUMN>
                <INDEX>1</INDEX>
                <NAME>userid</NAME>
                <INCLUDE>true</INCLUDE>
            </COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>
                <INDEX>2</INDEX>
                <NAME>EMAIL</NAME>
                <INCLUDE>true</INCLUDE>
            </COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>
                <INDEX>3</INDEX>
                <NAME>firstName</NAME>
                <INCLUDE>true</INCLUDE>
            </COLUMN>
            <COLUMN>
                <INDEX>4</INDEX>
                <NAME>lastName</NAME>
                <INCLUDE>true</INCLUDE>
            </COLUMN>
        </MAPPING>
    </LIST_IMPORT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with Silverpop customer support, who said my files and call were working just fine for them, we determined the problem.  The XML declaration:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Needs to be the first thing in the document.  Although it appears that it is above, there are actually several tab stops before it.  While Silverpop's tools were trimming those extraneous characters out, ColdFusion was send it exactly as it was, and Silverpop's server just returned a generic error.

The solution was to remove those tab stops, or trim the xml right before sending.